# What do the numbers mean on the users page?

Tags: support

If you look on the Users page you see a number next to the profile picture. What does this number mean as it doesn't look related to their reputation?

Comment: you mean the monthly reputation number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default sort on `/users` is by reputation, and the default **time frame** is the current month.  The following screenshot shows the monthly rep gains by each of the associated users:

[image]

Additionally, the tags shown are the tags for which the user has earned the most rep in the time frame.

Select a time frame of 'all' to view the ordinary rep statistics.

Comment: Freehand circles!!!